# Select value returns null in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-6">
 <select class="no-padding" id="ddlPaymentTerm" name="ProductDetails.PaymentTerm" style="width: 100%;"></select>
</div>
```

the option list is populated using Jquery.
and when get value from jquery it returns null

```
var payment_term = $("#ddlPaymentTerm").val();
```

if have tried

```
var payment_term = $("#ddlPaymentTerm option:selected").val();
```

the values is there and selected, i can see using developers tool.

Comment: Your HTML is missing the final closing double quote and angle bracket, and an `option` element. Once you correct that, the code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/fn48gc2p/

Comment: Your `select` is invalid and has no `option`s.

Comment: The option list is populated using Jquery...

Comment: @YasirJaved you probably should have clarified that in your post. As it stands your issue isn't reproducable since your example code is invalid.

Comment: @YasirJaved where is the code which adds the `option` elements? Are you trying to get the `val()` *before* that happens?

Comment: Roy no dropdown is populated and then select the value and then only try to get the value

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct your html and at least add one option element inside your html tag...

```js
var payment_term = $("#ddlPaymentTerm").val();
console.log(payment_term);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-6">
 <select class="no-padding" id="ddlPaymentTerm" name="ProductDetails.PaymentTerm" style="width: 100%;">
  <option value="someValue">some value</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you didn't add `option` tags to your html.
Try this:

```
<div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-6">
   <select class="no-padding" id="ddlPaymentTerm" name="ProductDetails.PaymentTerm" style="width: 100%;">
      <!-- Add your options here  -->
      <option value="1">Option1</option>
      <option value="2">Option2</option>
   </select>
</div>
```